# Bind generic list to WPF datagrid and sort it

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, data-binding, datagrid

Regarding [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44198272/wpf-datagrid-refresh-after-sorting-not-working) and the answer, I've looked into it, and I know use following line to make a programmatically bind between the generic list and the datagrid:

```
LibraryView.SetValue(DataGrid.ItemsSourceProperty, _manager.Library.Songs);
```

It works, and sorts visually (without arrow in the columnheader though), but like mentioned in the answer, it implicitly uses a ICollectionView. Now my question is how can I reflect the sorting to the binded datasource, in my case the generic list. I've found how to do it with winforms, but it was more complex then I would expect and I couldn't convert it to WPF.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why and when do you want to sort the source collection, i.e. _manager.Library.Songs?

Comment: Because I use that datasource as "playlist", so the order should be the same as the view and when clicking on the columnheader like you normally would.

Comment: This answer is for winforms but I couldn't convert it to WPF (since i'm new to WPF): https://stackoverflow.com/a/2551416/5985593

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the view to sort the source collection, you could cast the `ItemsSource` property of the `DataGrid` to your collection type and sort this one. Of course this requires you to know *how* to sort the sort collection and what kind of source collection you are dealing with.

If `_manager.Library.Songs` is a `List<T>` you could for example use the `List<T>.Sort` method to sort it:

```
private void dg_Sorting(object sender, DataGridSortingEventArgs e)
{
    var sourceCollection = dg.ItemsSource as List<Item>;
    if (sourceCollection != null)
    {
        var sortDirection = e.Column.SortDirection;
        switch (sortDirection)
        {
            default:
            case ListSortDirection.Descending:
                sortDirection = ListSortDirection.Ascending;
                break;
            case ListSortDirection.Ascending:
                sortDirection = ListSortDirection.Descending;
                break;
        }

        int direction = (sortDirection == ListSortDirection.Ascending ? 1 : -1);
        string property = e.Column.SortMemberPath;
        switch (property)
        {
            case nameof(Item.X):
                sourceCollection.Sort((x, y) => x.X.CompareTo(y.X) * direction);
                break;
                //...and so on for all properties/columns
        }
    }
}
```

But in general a view is not supposed to sort the source collection that it is bound to.

Answer (score 0):

You can create `ICollectionView` yourself and directly bind both of your controls to it, for example using a class `ViewableCollection` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43255050/891715) and access the `ViewableCollection.View` for the sorted/filtered collection. This way you'll only sort once and the changes are reflected across all controls. The default sorting behaviour of `DataGrid` will also work without extra code, plus you can sort from codebehind by simply adding/clearing current `SortDescriptions` on `ViewableCollection.View`.

If you choose to use this solution, it is important to remember to bind `ItemsSource` property to `ViewableCollection.View` not the collection itself.

On the surface it works similarly as binding directly to `DataView` of `DataTable` in Forms from two different controls.